# Regex Multiple Lines AHK

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I am trying to workout a solution to get a regexmatch to a string that are in between 2 text, I came up with a working solution of

```
RegExMatch(clipboard,"STUFF<p class=""figure"">(.*)</p></div><",match)
```

that matches the things from (gave me 2140)

```
<div><div>STUFF<p class="figure">2140</p></div></div>
```

but this is all in a single line, I have no idea how do I apply this to a code that are multiple line, such as

```
<tr>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>    
        310
    </td>   
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to get 310, how should my regex be? I couldn't figure out how, I've tried with \s\s but to no avail. Please help

EDIT

I seem to get a hang of \s* function now, I tried it slowly to see where it omits, as I go on with

```
<td>Qty</td>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>
```

it gave me :

but I couldn't get it pass the `<td>`:`</td>` part, it always returns blank, I am wondering if my (.*?) should be (.\s*?) instead?

I tried

```
RegExMatch(clipboard,"<td>Qty</td>\s*<td>(.\s*?)</td>\s*</tr‌​>",match)
```

but to no avail

Comment: Use `\s*` for space like characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that you add `\s*` where ever you think a space might come. It will match zero or space like characters. (like tabs, new lines etc). For example,
`\s*<tr>\s*<td>Qty</td>\s*<td>:</td>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>/s*</tr>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i seem to get a hang of \s* function now, i tried it slowly to see where it omits, as i go on with  

<td>Qty</td>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>  
it gave me :
  
but i couldn't get it pass the <td>:</td> part, it always return blank, i am wondering if my (.*?) should be (.\s*?) instead?   
I tried   
RegExMatch(clipboard,"<td>Qty</td>\s*<td>(.\s*?)</td>\s*</tr>",match)

Comment: Well your `<td>Qty</td>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>` doesn't contain the `<td>:</td>`, thats why it doesnt match. Try: `<td>Qty</td>\s*<td>:</td>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>`. You can use `\s*` as it will match 0 or more instances of a match.